# Create a list of files in a directory with a certain char

Tags: files, find

I would like to be able to list all files within a folder which have a certain character as the third character.  For each file, I then want to be able to perform an action, maybe delete or move.  I've looked at the ls command, with grep/cut options, but I can't see how to get final list that I can then process.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, it's only 1 level, not recursive.  Thanks for the feedback.   I will check which works and select the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use "find" command to find files and perform an action for each file individually.

```
find <directory_name> -name '??t*' -exec mv {} <target_directory> \;
```

Comment: This is better but searches recursively which (I think) is not what OP wants (though OP should clarify) and also lists directories.

Comment: add `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` to only find files in that one directory.

Comment: xargs is another option here; 

    `ls ??t* | xargs -I {} mv {} <target_directory>`

Comment: Better yet, `mkdir -p targetdir && mv ??t* targetdir`...

Comment: ASevkin - why do you need the error prone `ls | xargs` when you can do it with `find` and do it right ? That is, if recursion is needed, otherwise you can simply glob - either way there's no point using `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some pattern matching directly in the shell without invoking external programs.

Let's say you have a folder with the following files:

```
$ ls
ant  bat  bird  cat  cats  dog  fish
```

You could match only files 3 characters long ending in `t` like this:

```
$ ls ??t
ant  bat  cat
```

You could match any file with the 3rd character as `t` like this:

```
$ ls ??t*
ant  bat  cat  cats
```

See more documentation here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Comment: The problem here is the second part of the question: _"For each file, I then want to be able to perform an action..."_ - and `ls` is not a good candidate for this job.

Comment: `for f in ??t*; do stuff with $f; done` ?